# What does this calligraphy state?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Assuming it is English, can you help understanding the longer word in the context. It seems like STAY ?RO?? to me.

[image: Vertical depiction]

[image: In context of the other word]

Comment: It looks to me like it says *STAY PRONG*. But that doesn't seem to make any sense, although it is a word.

Comment: This could be a reference to the metal band [**Prong**.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prong_(band)) They have an album called *Scorpio Rising*, which might explain the scorpion.

Comment: My first guess is “STAY DRONG”, which makes no more sense than “PRONG”. My second guess, which makes sense language-wise but not visually, is that the first character of the second word is a combination “ST”, which makes the phrase “STAY STRONG”.

Comment: The calligraphic style looks to me like an ornate version of German Fraktur style, and is definitely ***STAY WRONG***.

Comment: @sumelic - Yeah, that was one of the 'problems' with Fraktur, but if you look carefully, in the 'M', the right 'vertical' extends past the lower piece of the middle vertical, while in the original picture, it doesn't. I'll grant that Preger...'s sample is a near-perfect match to the original, but in variants I've seen, there was always variation in T and W, and frequently confusable similarity between capital i and J, and between B and V, less often between A and U, and M and W.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with the English Language, but interpretation of a photograph of logo, itself unsuitable for SE.

Comment: @David well, to be sure, it doesn't seem it could really fit on cryptography either, so maybe this se is the most efficient fit for that question? Where would you send it?

Comment: @RaceYouAnytime - suggest might be close. The H&M shop also resurrected a [METALLICA print](http://www.hm.com/us/product/75317?article=75317-A&cm_vc=PRA1) for their line. Maybe they like obscure metal bands. But fact that chat rep don't know about it leaves doubts.

Answer (score 11):

It reads "stay wrong", an ironic play on words based on the common encouragement "stay strong".

Comment: From the other answer, it actually looks like the "W" is really an "M". But that just makes it wronger.

Comment: that was one guess that looked close. Except the P/D looking letter has that distinctive top bar, and only one clear up stroke not two like a W

Comment: Maybe the T-shirt designer asked for "STAY ʍRONG", with an upside-down "W". But somebody completely fuddled the message when they put it into Fraktur.

Answer (score 5):

Here can be seen the sample fraktur style. [image: Sample fraktur style]
There does look very similar V to the suspected. D/P/W letter. But VRONG mst be wrong too.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the design was intended to say STAY STRONG or STAY WRONG, but the factory goofed it up. One of two things happened after that.

1. The fashion store that ordered it was stuck with the result because it came off the boat in a huge order and they had to sell it anyway. So they refused to pay the remainder of their order and pushed the article to buyers who think it's trendy because of the store brand.
2. The original purchaser told the Indonesian factory to eat the failure and refund the money for the intended purchase and the Indonesian factory then hocked the goods to H&M brand for virtual pennies.

Either way, [H&M Store brand](http://www.hm.com/us/product/73331?article=73331-E) decided to sell this defective merchandise, at a huge profit taking their customers for a ride, because the customers live for the status of the brand, not the actual design.

This happens often in big retail clothes outlets who deal with inexpensive labor to produce huge orders.

UPDATE: After copy pasting letters from screenshot of the chart provided. I agree the word says MRONG. Regardless of intention from the retailer or designer or mistake, the end result is MRONG.

[image]

In context, it states nothing in English, unless you accept the Urban Dictionary meaning: mrong = A man who shows/tells you what you have done wrong.

There could a far out possibility that MRONG has some meaning in Vietnamese, for there are some people named Mrong on Twitter and cities with Mrong in the name.

Comment: So what *does* it say? This appears to be a rant against buying practices, rather than answering the question.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I guess what he's trying to convey is that it doesn't say anything : ) Even H&M describes it as "motif". An equivalent of pseudo-Chinese tattoos.

Comment: And we all know what happens when you make up some Chinese characters (or ask a less than scrupulous tattooist to translate a given phrase). Yes, it looks nice, but.

Answer (score 1):

I often think that my inability to read graffiti on walls and messages on clothing is yet [further](https://www.porchdrinking.com/articles/2017/01/11/beer-is-proof-that-god-loves-us-and-wants-us-to-be-happy/) proof that G-d loves me and loves to see me happy. So I’ve fallen into the habit of giving these things no thought whatsoever. But ndasusers contributed the fact (which I would not have known) that the shirt is from H&M. So I went to their website and began a LIVE CHAT. Because Courtney, his or her manager and I were all simultaneously alive at 11:05 this morning, we were able to chat as follows.

Courtney: Welcome to live chat with H&M, I am Courtney. I'll be helping you out today.

You: Hi Courtney. I’m looking at a Hooded Sweatshirt with Motif, Art. No. 04-4320. There’s some ornate lettering on the shirt that seems to say “STRAY PRONG.” Can you tell me what it really says? Or, if it says STAY PRONG, what does this mean?

Courtney: Let me see

Courtney: Thanks for your patience

Courtney: I am going to give my manager a call to look into it because I am also having trouble reading it.

Courtney: I am speaking with them now.

Courtney: Thank you for your patience

Courtney: Some of the ornate lettering that we have is just for decoration so there is no meaning at all. Sorry for any confusion

You: Okay. Thanks for your help. Do you think it says STAY PRONG?

Courtney: It may, like I said it is just for decoration so there is no meaning behind it

You: Okay, Goodbye.

Courtney: :)

So if I'm reading that right, Courtney is also happy.